# I/O operation on closed file at transmitting files via Webhook

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio, webhooks

I am using the following code to transmit a message without a `discord.Embed` to all servers using an `asyncio.Queue`. However, the discord guilds receive a `discord.Embed` object from the `create_content` function, which is created when the `on_message` event is called.

Code for transmitting messages via Webhook:

```py
                    item = await global_queue.get()
                    if item[3] != "DELETE":
                        Start = time.time()
                        find_globals = await get_query("global-bot_new", "SELECT channel_id, guild_id, webhook_url FROM global_channels")
                        find_globals = find_globals.fetchall()

                        Start1 = time.time()

                        msgids: list = []
                        guild_ids: list = []
                        channel_ids: list = []

                        files: list = []
                        if item[6][4] == 1:
                            for entry in item[6][1].copy():
                                file = discord.File(entry[0], filename=str(entry[1]))
                                print(file)
                                files.append(file)

                        async def iteration(x):
                            x1: list = [x]
                            # .. previous code .. 

                            try:
                                embed_list: list = item[0].embeds
                            except IndexError:
                                embed_list = item[7]

                            content: str = ""
                            if design == 1:
                                content = item[6][0]
                                if item[6][4] == 1:
                                    files.pop(0)
                                bot_name = item[6][2]
                                bot_avatar = item[6][3]
                                embed_list = []

                            # get webhook
                            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                                webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(str(x1[0][2]), session=session)

                                try:
                                    msg = await webhook.send(content=content, embeds=embed_list, files=files, wait=True,
                                                             username=bot_name,
                                                             avatar_url=bot_avatar)
                                except discord.NotFound:
                                    webhook = await create_webhook(self.client, channel)
                                    if webhook is None:
                                        await delete_guild(x1[0][1])
                                        await leave_guild(guild)
                                        return None

                                    try:
                                        msg = await webhook.send(content=content, embeds=embed_list, files=files, wait=True,
                                                                 username=bot_name,
                                                                 avatar_url=bot_avatar)
                                    except:
                                        return None

                                    return msg.id, guild.id, channel.id
                                except (discord.HTTPException, discord.Forbidden):
                                    return None
                                except Exception as e:
                                    traceback.print_exc()
                                    print(e)
                                else:
                                    return msg.id, guild.id, channel.id

                        # and so on..
```

This is what the `create_design` function looks like:

```py
async def create_design(message: discord.Message, invite: str, bots: str, level: int, design: int, avatar_bytes: io.BytesIO, animated: bool):
    design_content: list = []

    guildname: str = f"`{message.guild.name}`"
    if len(invite) > 0:
        guildname = f"**[{message.guild.name}](<{invite.replace('・ [`` Server beitreten](', '')[:-1]}>)**"

    content = f"× Gesendet von {guildname} (`{len(message.guild.members)}` - `{bots}`)\n\n" \
              f"_{message.content}_"

    bot_name = f"@{message.author.name} ~ Level {level}"
    bot_avatar = str(message.author.display_avatar.url)

    design_content.append(content)

    files: list = []
    if animated:
        filename = "avatar.gif"
    else:
        filename = "avatar.png"
    files.append((avatar_bytes, filename))

    design_content.append(files)
    design_content.append(bot_name)
    design_content.append(bot_avatar)
    design_content.append(design)
    return design_content
```

This is how I send the item to the `asyncio.Queue`:

```py
        avatar, animated, avatar_bytes = await self.handler(message)
        files.insert(0, avatar)
        
        ..

        design_content = await create_design(message, invite, bots, level, design, avatar_bytes, animated)

        await msg.delete()
        gembed_list = embed_list
        if design == 1:
            content = design_content[0]
            gembed_list = []
            files = design_content[1].copy()
            files.pop(0)
            bot_name = design_content[2]
            bot_avatar = design_content[3]

        # some other code stuf..

        code = generate(length_minimal=2, length_maximal=24, int_max_length=24, int_min_length=1)
        await global_queue.put(
            [msg, message, code, "MESSAGE", message.author.guild.id, message.author.id, design_content, embed_list])
```

---

So far, this works quite well. However, my problem is that it doesn’t transmit the `files` correctly. It generates an `avatar.gif` (as example) file, but it is exactly 0 bytes in size and sometimes I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Bots/global-bot-v3/cogs/misc_events.py", line 218, in iteration
    msg = await webhook.send(content=content, embeds=embed_list, files=files, wait=True,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
..
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I have been working on a solution for days, but I can’t find a way to fix it. I don’t see any errors in the code. It creates the Embed and saves the `avatar_bytes`, then creates `design_content` based on the variables, transmits it to the `asyncio.Queue`, and for some reason, it seems that it can’t `process` the files correctly.

Can anyone help me figure out what’s going wrong and how to fix it?